# Printing non duplicate in C array

Tags: c, arrays

I was working on a program for my intro to C class (xtra credit assignment) and can't figure out how to discard duplicates numbers on an array. The problem asks to only print non duplicates; so I able to print the first number, compare the following and print if different, I discard the next if a duplicate, but the thing is I've only figured out how to compare the one number it following one, I figured I could do another for loop inside the for loop, but I'm getting super confused and just can't figure it out. I've already submitted my code last week, I've just been working on this trying to figure it out for myself so any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

*"EDIT: Here's the problem: Use a single-subscripted array to solve the following problem. Read in 20 numbers, each of which is between 10 and 100, inclusive. As each number is read, print it only if it's not a duplicate of a number already read. Provide for the worst case in which all 20 numbers are different. Use the smallest possible array to solve this problem"*

Thanks in advance, and any advice on how I'm writing my program would also be appreciated as I'm a total noob, and trying to be a good programmer with as little bad habits as possible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define AS 20

void findDuplicate (int af[], int fAS);

int main(){

    int a[AS], i , j, k;
    int last = 0;

    printf("Enter %d numbers between 10 and 100:\n", AS);

    for (i = 0; i < AS; i++){
        scanf("%d",&a[i] );
        if (a[i] >= 10 && a[i] <= 100 ){
            continue;
        } else {
            printf("You must enter values between 10 - 100\n");
            i = i -1;
        }   
    }

    findDuplicate(a, AS);

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}



void findDuplicate (int af[], int fAS){
    int c;

    printf("You entered ");

    for (c=0; c < fAS; c++){
            if (af[c] != af[c+1]){
                printf("%d ", af[c]);
            }
            continue;
        }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: If you don't have to print the numbers in the original order, you can just sort the array before doing your check.

Comment: doesn't this code cause you a segmentation fault. If not, you are a lucky one.

Comment: and your question is not specified properly. Can you give some cases of I/O, and can a number (that you are calling duplicate) can be repeated more than twice in your array, can they be in any order etc

Comment: If the numbers are all between 10 and 100 (not a lot of possible values) you could  use another array to indicate which values have been found already (eg. `found[18]` could be 0 if 18 hasn't been found or 1 if it has)

Comment: @vish4071: Why *would* this segfault?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You should give an example.

Comment: Here's the problem:  Use a single-subscripted array to solve the following problem.
Read in 20 numbers, each of which is between 10 and 100, inclusive. 
As each number is read, print it only if it's not a duplicate of a number already read. Provide for the worst case in which all 20 numbers are different. Use the smallest possible array to solve this problem.

Comment: actually your line of code : if (af[c] != af[c+1]) , goes out of bounds at c=AS-1, as c+1 = AS and af[AS] is not defined. Anyway, you should give sample I/O atleast, or solution given by Dmitri should work too. 
See "HASHING"

Comment: @vish4071 tnx but I don't see what you mean by not defined, would you mind sharing how you'd write this or how you would do it differently please? Tnx

Comment: Tnx y'all very much for your responses back to the drawing board and figure it out.

Comment: By not defined, I meant: "When you define an array of size (say)20, like int a[20], then it has index values ranging 0-19, and you can NOT access a[20] which goes out of bounds." If you ever do programming on online judges, corner code handling such as this is important or it definitely gives segfault.

Comment: @vish4071 Aaaahhhh  tnx a lot, so my AS constant should be 19 correct? cause 20 numbers would be stored in subsets 0 -19, tnx again Vish.

Comment: nope...you are not getting the point. Change AS to 19, then read my above comment replacing all '20' with '19'. You can rectify this using (c < fAS - 1) inside for loop and handling case for af[19]

Answer (score 0):

You should first define an Array which can save as many variables as you want ..
Lets say you are comparing for 10-100 which means 91 possible different digits.

so , define array with the size of 91. and then do the scanning in for loop for 91 times to find out if you have that variable entered previously. If not then save it and display it ,else discard it.

Comment: duh, can't believe I didn't think of this, now back to the drawing board to figure out, lol Tnx a lot Nirmal